# Flutter: SHA1 key doesn't work for debug, but works for release

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Description: I'm trying to connect an existing flutter project to the new Firestore database I've created, which I'm using as a Development database. I've built an apk for the app, on which authentication and everything else work fine. But when I run it directly from android studio, authentication doesn't work.

The SHA1 I generated looks like this:

```
Variant: debugAndroidTest
Config: debug
Store: C:\Users\Alula\.android\debug.keystore
Alias: AndroidDebugKey
MD5: **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
SHA1: **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
SHA-256: **:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**:**
Valid until: Wednesday, October 11, 2053
```

I entered the SHA1 onto the app on the Dev db, got the google-services.json generated, and pasted it under the android/app directory. I also entered the dependencies for google services on build.gradle files.

What should I do differently to run it directly from Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for creating SHA1 fingerprint for Debug & Release mode:

For Debug mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore %USERPROFILE%/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

For Release mode:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

Example:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore C:\Users\Shejan\Desktop\example.jks -alias example
```

> On windows, when keytool command is not found, Go to your installed JDK Directory e.g. \Java\jdk1.8.0_231\bin, open command line and try the above commands for debug/release mode.

Another way of getting your SHA1 OR SHA-256 use `./gradlew signingReport`

Comment: the sha1 generated by the suggested method yields the same fingerprint as before.

Comment: clear everything from `google-services.json` and go to firebase re-enter your SHA-1 on required field and download `google-services.json` then copy content & paste into android studio

Comment: It worked after implementing the suggestion you gave, and then running `flutter clean`, and `flutter pub get` in that order.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add debug sha keys also. to get debug `sha` key run this command in terminal in your project directory

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

you be prompted to enter password enter `android` as password and you will get debug `sha` and `md5` keys.

Comment: the sha1 generated by the suggested method yields the same fingerprint as before.